# DateTime Format in BizTalk Orchestration

Tags: c#, biztalk

I have a requirement where I have a field in a XML which is string datatype which is being distinguished contains datetime as " 2019-12-04T13:44:44.000+00:00 " which I need to format to "  " 2019-12-04 13:44:44.000 " . I know how this can be done in BizTalk map script functoid but need help inside an orchestration

Comment: Can you not just call `result = System.DateTime.Parse(dateString);` in an expression shape?